# How to parse this text into a tree?

Tags: clojure, tree

I want to take text (sample below) and convert it into a nested data structure that can be walked:

```
Arbirarchy !
  dog, my friend
    Bailey the Great
  cats, my enemies
    Robert the Terrible
    Trev the Diner
    Gombas the Tasty
      Lenny Lion
  Alligators
    Sadly I have none
```

Comment: can you please elaborate further?

Comment: is Gombas meant to be indented?

Comment: To provide context: I'm building a text editor that allows one to use indentation to indicate a tree structure. The tree structure is to be mirrored in a ticketing system, where related tasks are grouped under a parent. Concretely, I want to take the text above and turn it into this: http://demo.redmine.org/projects/stack123/issues?query_id=160

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Is this the solution?

```
(defn parse [s]
  {(re-find #"(?m)^.+" s)
   (map parse (map #(str/replace % #"(?m)^\s{2}" "")
                   (map first (re-seq #"(?m)(^\s{2}.+(\n\s{4}.+$)*)" s))))})
```

your string (supposed that "Gombas" is indented):

```
(def s "hierarchy\n  dog\n    Bailey\n  cats\n    Robert\n    Trev\n    Gombas")
```

test

```
(parse s)
-> {"hierarchy" ({"dog" ({"Bailey" ()})}
                 {"cats" ({"Robert" ()}
                          {"Trev" ()}
                          {"Gombas" ()})})}
```

Comment: Eh, using regular expressions to attempt to parse a tree structure usually isn't such a great idea. Then again, neither is indicating a tree structure by indention.

Comment: @Cubic 1. Could you clarify this? 2. It depends.

Comment: I appreciate the effort but it's not quite what I am looking for. I have modified my original tree of text to show the text can be quite arbitrary.

Comment: I've modified "parse" too. Just replaced "\w" with ".". It works again for your data.